# How do I get the managers/contributors/etc of a Google Team Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Team Drive has five permission levels:

- Manager
- Content Manager
- Contributor
- Commenter
- Viewer

The [Folder API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder), on the other hand, only has three functions for getting a user list of people on a folder:

- `getEditors()`
- `getOwner()`
- `getViewers()`

This works fine if you're using a My Drive, because it has those exact same three levels:

- Is Owner
- Can organize, add, & edit
- Can view only

How do I get each of the 5 access levels in a Google Team Drive? If I do call those 3 functions, which access level do they correspond to on a Team Drive? (E.g. does `getEditors` return everyone in the `Manager` group?)

I see there is a [Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission) enum with the exact 5 permissions I'm looking for:

- `VIEW`
- `EDIT`
- `COMMENT`
- `OWNER`
- `ORGANIZER`

... and I can call [`getAccess()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getAccess(String)) to get the access level given a `User` or `email`. Problem is I don't know which `email`s to pass to the function.

How do I get a list of people in any of the 5 categories (e.g. `Content Manager`)? Or how do I get a list of all people that are on the Team Drive (e.g. so I know which emails to use with `getAccess()`)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a summary of the mappings between the permissions given in the Team Drive UI, the corresponding `getAccess()` value, and the Folder API method you can call which contains that person:

```
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Team Drive Permission | getAccess() | Folder API Method |
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Manager               | ORGANIZER   | (None)            |
| Content Manager       | NONE        | (None)            |
| Contributor           | EDIT        | getEditors()      |
| Commenter             | COMMENT     | getViewers()      |
| Viewer                | VIEW        | getViewers()      |
| (None)                | NONE        | (None)            |
+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Some results:

- **There is no way to know who is a Content Manager on the Team Drive**: Notice how it returns `NONE` for both **Content Manager**s and people who aren't on the Team Drive. It is therefore impossible to know who is a Content Manager on the Team Drive using the `getAccess()` method, even if you know the person's email address. This may be a bug in the API?
- **You can easily get all Contributors**: Simply call the `getEditors()` method.
- **You can get all Commenters and Viewers, but need to use `getAccess()` too**: Since both Commenters and Viewers are return via `getViewers`, you'll need to cross reference this against the results returned in getAccess() to find the actual Commenters or Viewers.
- **There are no API methods to get the Manager or Content Managers**: None of the standard API methods that return a set of users on a Folder will return anyone in the Manager or Content Manager group. You therefore need to know the email address of the managers, and can only use getAccess() to verify that they are indeed Managers.
- **`getOwner()` always returns `null`**. Presumably this is because there are no single owners on Team Drives. It will return `null` even if you have exactly 1 Manager and 0 Content Managers.

Therefore, there doesn't seem to be a way to find the `OWNER`s or `ORGANIZER`s on a Team Drive (presumably the **Managers** and **Content Managers**, respectively) using the standard API. Instead, you must already know what the email address associated with the user is, and call `getAccess()`. This is unfortunate.

I was expecting the following workaround to work:

- Create a dummy file inside the Team Drive. Since *file* permissions inside a Team Drive map to exactly **Edit**, **Comment**, **View**, the `getEditors()` method should now expose the Manager and Content Managers. Since they have the **Edit** permission on the file, they should presumably be returned by the `getEditors()` method.

This unfortunately didn't work either. The results were *exactly* the same as the *folder* case. The Manager and Content Manager were hidden (i.e. none of the 3 methods returned them). The Content Manager's getAccess() was still NONE, etc.

---

To get the list of Managers and Content Managers, then, I believe the only option is to use the advanced API. In particular, it looks like `teamDrivePermissionDetails[].role` on the [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) object returns exactly the 5 states that map to Team Drive permissions:

> - organizer
> - fileOrganizer
> - writer
> - commenter
> - reader