# In Google AppScripts how do we add Content Manager permissions for a folder in Shared Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In the AppScripts API Reference, adding permissions on a folder has two settings: addEditor(emailAddress) and addViewer(emailaddress). Is there anyway, we can add "content manager" permissions on the folder using AppScripts?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190301/11225291) answer there is no API regarding Content Managers. Not sure if the current answer in this post will answer your question, but you may have to find a workaround or request it as a feature in the issueTracker.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Scripts has two ways to work with Google Drive:

1. The built-in [`DriveApp` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), which has a friendly API for performing most drive functions.
2. The advanced [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference), enabled in "Advanced Google Services". By default, this class is named `Drive`. Note: As of today, Google only allows you to use v2 of this API in Google Apps Script, not the newest revision v3. Be sure to refer to the v2 docs for the Drive API - there are differences with the permissions call used below.

As you've realized, DriveApp doesn't offer the full set of permissions for shared drives. You can add some permissions, like editor:

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(sharedFolderId).addEditor(email);
```

To access all shared drive permissions, you need to activate the full ("advanced") Google Drive API and use [`Drive.Permissions.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert). This code, as mentioned, is for API v2:

```
  Drive.Permissions.insert({ // This method name is "insert" in v3
    'role': 'fileOrganizer', // Displayed in the UI as "Content Manager"
    'type': 'user',
    'value': email, // This field name is "emailAddress" in v3
  }, sharedFolderId, {
    'supportsAllDrives': true, // Must be true for shared drives
  });
```

Mapping of permissions to the way they're displayed in the UI:

- organizer: Manager
- fileOrganizer: Content Manager
- writer: Contributor
- reader: Viewer
- reader with `additionalRoles` commenter: Commenter

Comment: Working on a similar issue, and I have it working where it doesn't fail, but it is still using Editor permissions only.  Here is what I have gotten, which works without error.

folder.addEditor(emailAddresses).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.FILE_ORGANIZER);

However, it still only does the editor.  Will post when I find out more but this syntax seems to be accepted user Drive API v3

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API has a generic method that can grant permissions to a group, please see `setSharing(accessType, permissionType)`:

```
// Creates a folder that anyone on the Internet can read from and write to. (Domain
// administrators can prohibit this setting for users of a Google Workspace domain.)
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Shared Folder');
folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

Permissions include edit, view, organize, etc...

References:

[Class Folder | Set Sharing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setsharingaccesstype,-permissiontype)

[Permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

[Enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)

Answer (score -1):

@jtatum your post was especially helpful!  I did mine using Drive API V3.  For those of you who don't understand what that means please [click the link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o8HN5yvlWcxQB_uzn113GcxNq_0o4kpZMkv2b8T2zFU/edit) and configure your settings before seeing the sample below:

A quick breakdown of the Drive.Permission API function, for a full list of the API constructs visit the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions) home page.  For this sample we will have:

- two variables
- two Configurations

  ```
   function setContentManagerPermission(){       
     var resourceid = "XYCDEFEGH12323" //This can be a file id or folder id
     var emailaddress = "johndoe@nodomain.com"

     var resource = {
       'role': 'fileOrganizer', // Grants Content Manager permissions.
       'type': 'user',
       'emailAddress': emailaddress
     }; //THIS IS A JSON STATEMENT

     //NOTE: resource must be passed in first
     Drive.Permissions.create(resource,resourceid,{
       'sendNotificationEmails': false,
       'supportsAllDrives': true
     });

   }
  ```
- Please note that resource variable has to be in json format.  I find working with JSON as a variable is easier for formatting.  You don't have to use this variable.  The varialbe supports native calls with the json in them.
- Also Drive.Permissions.Insert has been replaced in V3 with
  Drive.Permission.Create.  Their is also update and delete as well
- Under Drive Permissions you MUST have supportsAllDrives set to true
  in order to work with Shared Drives.  This will not work without it.

I hope this helps, it has been tested and works great.